# jQuery Manipulate JSON Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have an API request that produces the final JSON array. How can i get out this:

```
"Key":"PCP","Payment":170.08
```

From the below array result:

```
{"VehicleResults":[{"Id":"0","FinanceProductResults":[{"Term":36,"AnnualMileage":10000,"Deposits":1000,"ProductResults":[{"Key":"PCP","Payment":170.08},{"Key":"HP","Payment":279.37}]}]}]}
```

It is probably easy, but I don't know JQuery that well unfortuantely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need jQuery for do what you need. You just have to save your Json answer in a variable and go through his properties to get the one that you need. For instance:

```
var myAnswer = {"VehicleResults":[{"Id":"0","FinanceProductResults":[{"Term":36,"AnnualMileage":10000,"Deposits":1000,"ProductResults":[{"Key":"PCP","Payment":170.08},{"Key":"HP","Payment":279.37}]}]}]}

myAnswer.VehicleResults[0].FinanceProductResults[0].ProductResults[0]
```

Comment: Thank you Brank! Works perfectly!